# crm 2013: bpf customization

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Can I customize the BPF in the following ways?

1. Initiate the BPF process instance based on criteria?
   I.E. Can I initiate a BPF process instance for Opportunities that belong to a certain team, not apply the BPF to all opportunities?
2. Customize the BPF ribbon button?
   I.E. Disable the 'Back button' on the BPF Ribbon?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Accept that this is a generic response for your question, appreciate if you could post specifically what do you meant by criteria and customize.

BPF do not actually run as system jobs (Initiate) in the way that workflows and dialogs do. Instead they provide a means of data entry and enforce a set of rules when a user interacts with record through a form. They cannot have any branching or conditional logic beyond required field steps to prevent the user from progressing without completing necessary information.

May be what you need can be achieved by combining different CRM features together like, Field Security, Business Rules and Workflows.

Comment: Thanks for your insights about BPF. I have added some examples.